# Making an HTML5 game an iPhone/iPad app in Apple's App Store

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, ipad, app-store

We are teaching how to make JavaScript games. Then we teach how to make the JavaScript game a pseudo-app by using Apple's custom `meta` tags to make it look like an app by adding a webpage to the home screen.

Is there a way to package up the HTML5, CSS and JavaScript into a native app that can be sold in the App Store? I know there are tools out there like PhoneGap and maybe even PhoneGap is the answer, but it looks like we have to use their API to create apps. I want to very simply take these students JavaScript games, run a command on them and submit them to Apple.

Is there a good super-easy solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PhoneGap's API to access native features, but you don't have to.

It's still not super-easy, but [build.phonegap.com](https://build.phonegap.com/) is free for one app and lets you upload a zip file with your code in it.

Comment: Sounds ideal. Are students able to then submit that app to Apple's App Store?

Comment: Only paid ios developers can submit

Answer (score 2):

You can try writing a simple wrapper app that just displays your html in a UIWebView.

As for releasing it, only a paid iOS developer member can submit apps to the app store.  That means either your students have to pay, or you pay and submit for your students.

Comment: Yes that would be the idea, we pay and submit for our students.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said
[Apache Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) (formerly Phonegap) does exactly what you want, and does not require you to use their APIs

Keep in mind, apple doesn't want the app store filled with *practice* apps.  They have an approval process that could take up to 2 weeks before an apple is approved.  And if each student submits the same app or very similar apps, most are sure to get rejected.

For teaching purposes:

- it may be better to go with a pure web approach that you can put on a website
- or put the app in Google Play store ($25 one time fee) without strict app policies

**Also** there is Cydia to distribute apps for jailbroken iphones, but *i wouldn't* teach that

Answer (score -2):

```
<!DOCType HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="write.js">
document.write("Text written using JavaScript code, done by 'el Jacko!");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing information on how and why it solves the problem improves its long-term value